# Execute function from start on error/timeout through Vb Script in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, msxml6

I have the following method in my `create.asp` page:

```
Public Function read(url)

    Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False, PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASSWORD
    xmlHttp.SetProxy 2, PROXY
    xmlHttp.SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    xmlHttp.Send


    xml.Async = False
    xml.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
    xml.ValidateOnParse = True

    xml.Load xmlHttp.ResponseXml

    Set read = xml

    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    Set xml = Nothing
End Function
```

The function works 9 times out of 10.

Problem: In rare occasions, it gives me a timeout error. For this reason, I have set `xmlHttp.Timeouts` to infinity. I have also tried using `On error` statements, but that does not resolve the issue.

Question: ****How do I execute the function from the start if it gives me any kind of error? **** The only error I have come across is the timeout error when it tries to execute `xmlHttp.Send`.

Any other possible solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: Since `xmlHttp.ResponseXml` returns a DOMDocument why are you loading it into a DOMDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a code problem, its most likely an issue with the proxy server.

If you want to be able to retry you can;

```
dim result
for i = 1 to 3 '//3 attempts
    set result = read("http://bla.bla")
    if (not result is nothing) then exit for
next

if (result is nothing) then
    '//repeatedly failed ...
else
    '//got a dom doc
end if

Public Function read(url)
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    on error resume next

    xmlHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlHttp.Send
    xml.Async = False
    xml.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
    xml.ValidateOnParse = True
    xml.Load xmlHttp.ResponseXml

    if (err.number = 0) then
        set read = xml
     else
        set read = nothing
     end if

    on error goto 0
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
    Set xml = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I have implemented the above solution and its working great as of now. Just a syntax doubt: do we need to check `if (result is nothing) then exit for` instead of `if (not result is nothing) then exit for`?  Could you please make me understand the statement?

Comment: If you used `if (result is nothing) then exit for` then you would exit the loop when there was no result rather than retrying.  
`if (not result is nothing) then exit for` exits the loop when there is a valid result; i.e. when `result` has been set to something

Comment: On timeout error, it just stops all execution though. Is there any other solution wherein if there is a timeout, it actually executes itself again rather then stop execution and throwing the error.

Comment: What line causes the timeout? .Send?

Comment: Yup. As I have mentioned in my question as well, it gives a timeout on Send(). However, the function has been running fine from the last time I commented out here. Hope it does not crash again. I will monitor it for sometime and if it works well, will accept your answer. Let me know if you have know of any other alternative to resolve this issue.